# An element that zeros all functionals is zero itself

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a linear normed space. Let $x\in X:\forall\varphi\in X^\ast,\varphi(x)=0$. Prove that $x=0$.

I thought taking $\varphi(y)=\Vert y\Vert$ but it's not a linear functional. How can I prove it?

Answer (score 4):

Let $x$ be non equal to zero.
By the Hahn Banach theorem, the functional defined by $\phi(x)=1$ on $\mathbb K.x$ can be extended in a functional $\phi'$ defined on all $X$ and we have $\phi'(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: @Svetoslav As long as $\phi(\lambda x) = \lambda$, I fail to see the problem. $x$ is only one element, after all.

Comment: @Lord_Farin , my bad.